# Why cannot a C++ compiler deduce the type of the lambda argument?

Tags: c++, template-argument-deduction

I've got the following code, which can't be compiled

```
template <typename T>
void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f, T val) {
    f(val);
}

int main() {
    auto print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
    call_with(print, 42);
}
```

And the compilation error looks like

```
tst.cpp:17:2: error: no matching function for call to 'call_with'
        call_with(print, 42);
        ^~~~~~~~~
tst.cpp:11:6: note: candidate template ignored: could not match 'function<void (type-parameter-0-0)>' against
      '(lambda at tst.cpp:16:15)'
void call_with(std::function<void(T)> f, T val) {
     ^
1 error generated
```

I tried to compile it with `g++ tst.cpp -o tst -std=c++17`

So I know sometimes C++ can deduce template arguments under some conditions, but I'm wondering why it cannot compile this code in this case. It looks like there cannot be any other options for a type `T` to be anything, but int and for `f` to be anything but `std::function<void(int)>`.

Comment: `std::function<void(double)>` can be constructed from `[](int){}`. So just because the lambda takes a parameter of type `T` doesn't mean the `std::function` has to take the parameter of the same type.

Comment: Ok, makes sense, but if we leave only ```T val``` argument, it is deduced correctly as ```int``` even though ```42``` can be treated as ```double```
So why there's an ambiguity with ```std::function``` and no ambiguity with a basic template argument ```T```?

Comment: Upon further consideration, I believe my first comment is misleading (it's technically correct but irrelevant to the question). The real reason is that template parameter deduction doesn't consider implicit conversions - it only performs a simple pattern matching on types. And the type `class L` (some unnamed class type synthesized for the lambda expression) doesn't match `std::function<void(T)>`

Comment: `42` cannot be treated as a double. `42` as an expression is an int, which can match a `T`. It's concrete. `std::function` erases the type of the callable (any callable) and it does so by conversions. Templates will not consider conversions when deducing things, by design, ever.

Comment: Consider: `std::function<void(T)>` has a constructor `template< class F > function( F f );` - on the surface, this can take anything. There's no way for the compiler to know that it's supposed to search the argument for all ways that a function call operator could be applied to it, and then pattern-match the types of parameters of such a function call - that's part of the semantics of `std::function` that's not in any way reflected in the syntax.

Comment: As a workaround, you could place the first `T` into a non-deduced context, e.g. as `template <typename T> void call_with(std::function<void(std::type_identity_t<T>)> f, T val)` (`type_identity_t` is a C++20 feature, but an equivalent can be trivially hand-rolled for earlier versions). This way, `T` would be unambiguously deduced from the second argument.

Comment: Hm, ok, interesting. So the compiler can actually deduce everything like there's enough information for it, but due to semantics of ```std::function``` it doesn't do that.

Comment: `call_with<int>(print, 42);` should fix the problem.

Comment: Expounding on *Templates will not consider conversions when deducing things, by design, ever.*  Why? Because compile times would take *factorially* longer.  And that's bad.

Comment: @Eljay Yeeeah, that looks like a true reason. Hm, but why is it factorial?

Comment: If you could restrict all functions to be monads, then it would only be *n*, but if the conversions are for every parameter then you have *n* x *n* x ... x *n*.

Answer (score 2):

Because `print` is not a `std::function<void(int)>`.And it can be converted to more than one valid type.

Try Run

```
    auto print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
    std::cout << typeid(print).name()<<"\n";
    std::function<void(unsigned __int64)> print_a = std::function<void(unsigned __int64)>(print);
    std::cout << typeid(print_a).name() << "\n";
    auto print_b = std::function<void(unsigned __int64)>(print);
    std::cout << typeid(print_b).name() << "\n";
```

You will get

```
class <lambda_d103cbf184cf5bdcf1494399ee6d564a>
class std::function<void __cdecl(unsigned __int64)>
class std::function<void __cdecl(unsigned __int64)>
```

Which shows `print` is a `lambda`,and it can be converted to many kinds of `std::function<void(T)>` like:

```
    auto print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
    auto print2 = std::function<void(unsigned __int64)>(print);
    auto print3 = std::function<void(unsigned short)>(print);
    auto print4 = std::function<void(char)>(print);
```

An exact `std::function<void(int)>` object can be deduced:

```
std::function<void(int)> print = [](int x) { std::cout << x; };
call_with(print, 42);
```

And **42 also need to be right type** for deducing

`std::function<void(int)>` + `int` means `T=int`

`std::function<void(short)>` + `short` means `T=short`

but `std::function<void(short)>` + `int` can't be deduced.
So you will get compile error on :

```
std::function<void(short)> print = [](short x) { std::cout << x; };
call_with(print, 42);
```

The right version is

```
std::function<void(short)> print = [](short x) { std::cout << x; };
call_with(print, short(42));
```

Comment: Mm, it seems a bit strange to me, like there's the same template typename ```T```, so if there are different candidates for ```function<void>(T)```, why can't compiler just take all the candidates, try then to deduce the second argument of the function (which is definitely ```int```) and leave only one candidate among all those, which is ```function<void>(int)```